# Getl All Checked Checkboxes not working with input="button"

Tags: javascript, jquery

I made a function that gets all checkboxex values..

```
$('input[type=checkbox]').each(function() {
  var sThisVal = 0;
  alert(this.checked);
  if (this.checked) {
    sThisVal = "1";
  } else {
    sThisVal = "0";
  }
  sList += (sList == "" ? sThisVal : "," + sThisVal);
});
```

When I create the button that executes this functions with the tag `<button>` works well... But i have to change to the tag `<input type='Button'>`. When I change, the function does not enter in `$('input[type=checkbox]').each()`

someone knows why?

If I rollback to the tag  works..

regards!!!

Rafael

Comment: You need double quotes around checkbox, to make it look as follows:
`$('input[type="checkbox"]')`

Comment: How do you bind event for clicking a button?

Comment: I think you're looking for `$("input:checkbox").each()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    sList = ''; 
    $('input[type=checkbox]').each(function () {
    var sThisVal = 0;
  if (this.checked) {
    sThisVal = "1";
  } else {
    sThisVal = "0";
  }
  sList += (sList == "" ? sThisVal : "," + sThisVal);
    });
alert(sList);
});
```

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/8jdooqp6/)